# Unit Testing Array Push

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mvvm, knockout.js, jasmine

This is probably a super obvious thing I'm missing but I'm trying to to push an existing object from one array into another for testing purposes but my tests keep failing.

**View Model**

```
this.userDatabases = ko.observableArray();
this.databases = _.range(5).map(function (i) {
    return {
        name: 'DB ' + (i + 1),
        chosenRoles: ko.observableArray(),
        chosenModules: ko.observableArray()
    };
});
```

**Unit Tests**

```
describe('modifies a new user by', function () {

    it('adding a database', function () {
        vm = new pfp.insight.controllers.settingsController();

        vm.userDatabases.push(vm.databases[0]);

        expect(vm.userDatabases.length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

This test is saying "Expected 0 to equal 1" and I'm not sure why the userDatabases isn't receiving the first object from the databases array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unwrap the observable array (by putting brackets after it) to test it's length, like so

```
    expect(vm.userDatabases().length).toEqual(1);
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple.  The whole time I was looking at the vm.userDatabases.push() logic and not the actual test.  Thanks!